# How to deploy a webjob through CI in VSO with vNext

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-devops

I'm trying to deploy a scheduled `webjob` through CI and `vNext` tasks in `VSO`.

I followed the steps in the following tutorial to deploy a `webjob` along with a web app ("Enable automatic deployment with a web project"):
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/

I succeeded partially: the `webjob` gets deployed along with the web application. However, it is marked as *On Demand* instead of *Scheduled* (or whatever the proper status is). I can run the webjob manually and it runs just fine. I checked the files `webjob-publish-settings.json` (in the webjob) and `webjobs-list.json` (in the web app) and they seem to be alright, judging from the tutorial.

Am I missing anything? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the cron expression to create the webjob scheduler if your app is running in Basic or High mode. Refer to this link for details: [Create a scheduled WebJob using a CRON expression](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON)

Otherwise, you need to [enable continues delivery of Azure Webjobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enabling-command-line-or-continuous-delivery-of-azure-webjobs/).

More reference: [Deploy your WebJobs projects with your Azure website using continuous delivery](http://chriskirby.net/deploy-your-webjob-projects-with-your-azure-website-using-continuous-delivery/)

Comment: Thanks again @Eddie. This article was very useful: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/#.VtB0WvkrJhE . The key was to find my settings in the debugging URL to make sure that it was getting the settings properly from settings.job. I eventually created a ticket in Kudu's project page for help. It turned out that my job was in a weird state but the folks at Kudu helped me fix it (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu). Thanks!