# Azure WebJob deploys as OnDemand instead of Scheduled

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops

I am trying to deploy a scheduled azure web job.  I have everything working except the job is being deployed as 'OnDemand'.

I am building and releasing using Visual Studio Team Services.

I have set up as follows:

[image]

The contents of the webjob-publish-settings.json are

```
{
 "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-  
  settings.json",
 "webJobName": "testCIJob"
}
```

And the settings.job are:

```
{"schedule": "0 0/10 0 0 0 0"}
```

which I believe is every 10 minutes, every day.

I have also linked my web job to my web app and have a webjobs-list.json file with the content:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjobs-list.json",
 "WebJobs": [
  {
     "filePath":     "../AscendancyCF.CmaServiceWebJob/AscendancyCF.CmaServiceWebJob.csproj"
   }
 ]
```

}

I have got this far searching the web but I find a lot of the information is rapidly out of date.  [an example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)

Also, I don't want to overload the question with information so if anyone needs more please just ask and I'll try and provide.

How do I get my web job to deploy on the schedule?

Comment: Did you by chance check how the Webjob is displayed on the ["Old" portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com)?

Comment: On Demmand there too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question is here:[How to deploy a webjob through CI in VSO with vNext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464820/how-to-deploy-a-webjob-through-ci-in-vso-with-vnext).

Try the solutions in it:

> You can use the cron expression to create the webjob scheduler if your
>   app is running in Basic or High mode. Refer to this link for details:
>   Create a scheduled WebJob using a CRON expression
>
> Otherwise, you need to enable continues delivery of Azure Webjobs.

Comment: Thanks Eddie,  I have 'always on' set.  I wonder if my settings.job is in the correct place and should I drop the json settings?

Comment: @davy Is "settings.job" file placed at the root of webjob directory? Make sure the properties "Copy to Output Directory" of "settings.job" file is set to "Copy always">

Comment: Thanks again Eddie, I thought I had but hadn't - this was the issue.  Everything is working,  :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Deploy Webjobs with Visual Studio](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/#publishsettings) article, the content of the `webjob-publish-settings.json` should be something like:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "WebJob1",
  "startTime": "2014-06-23T00:00:00-08:00",
  "endTime": "2070-06-27T00:00:00-08:00",
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Minute",
  "interval": 10,
  "runMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

That should run every 10 minutes until 2070. There is one note on the article tho that you might want to keep in mind:

> If you configure a Recurring Job and set recurrence frequency to a
>   number of **minutes**, the Azure Scheduler service **is not free**. Other
>   frequencies (hours, days, and so forth) are free.

Comment: thanks. this is what I started with but it doesn't work either.  A few places said use the settings.job file instead.

Comment: Another option is to create your functions using the [TimeTrigger](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/extensible-triggers-and-binders-with-azure-webjobs-sdk-1-1-0-alpha1/) from the Azure Webjobs SDK.