# Visual Studio Team Services, continuous deployment and WebJobs

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

Has anyone managed so set up a working deploy pipeline using Visual Studio Team Services RELEASE tasks? All the info I can find seem to be based on the Nuget publishing package which takes its parameters directly from the source. I am trying to get this working in the proper release workflow with multiple environments, dev to QA to prod pipeline etc.

The tooling does not seem to be in place for that scenario - or at least, I cannot figure out any combination of parameter where the powershell publish task in VSTS actually populates the app_data folder and sets up the schedule.

Frankly I am completely stumped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Azure Web App Deployment" task to deploy your WebJobs and use [CRON expression](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON) to set up the schedule.

A similar questions for your reference: [How to deploy a webjob through CI in VSO with vNext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464820/how-to-deploy-a-webjob-through-ci-in-vso-with-vnext)

Comment: Actually, my experience has been that the Web App deployment task fails to deploy a WebJob - there is no app_data folder when you use this task. The same applies to the publish-azurewebsiteproject command directly from Powershell; Webjobs do not deploy properly even if they are correctly packaged in the web deploy ZIP file.

Comment: I also forgot to mention in my original post that WebJobs pose an additional challenge because they typically require multiple connection strings - usually 3 or more. There does not seem to be any way to provide this to the deploy task - it requires a single name:value pair for the connection string and throws an exception otherwise.

Comment: @Schistad The WebJob is stored in under the "App_Data" folder of your website. Do you have website deployed before deploy the webjob?

Comment: So what I've so far seen is that a Web Deploy Package that works fine directly from Visual Studio, or through the msdeploy script contained in the build folder, does not get installed properly when deployed using the Web App deployment task in VSTS release.

Since I know that the Web Application task uses powershell, and specifically the "publish-azurewebsitepackage" commandlet in Azure POwershell, I have also offline tested - using the exact same package that VS deployed correctly - and verified that no, the app_data folder is missing from the Web App, and there is no Web Job set up.

Comment: You can check your azure web app to see if the app_data exist under /site/wwwroot/, if not, create one and then try the deployment from VSTS. You can also use FTP Uploader task to deploy the webjobs, this task should be able to create the app_data automatically. Check this link for details: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs